# vscode+Arduino environment: vscode is not able to load system headers despite the configuration of paths

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino

I'm really getting frustrated with this issue.

I have installed vscode(version: 1.69.2) & Arduino IDE(version 1.8.20) on my MacOS(version 12.5), I installed the Arduino extension in the vscode, and tried to get it work.

It just works fine if I don't include the system libraries, however if I tried to include a header file, example, the 'iostream', the complier prompts me as below:

```
Alternatives for iostream: []
ResolveLibrary(iostream)
  -> candidates: []
main:1:10: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
```

It looks like the VScode IntelliSense could find this file, if I click this file with Command key pressed, it will show me the location of it.

[iostream can be found by vscode IntelliSense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irKEY.jpg)

I'm assuming that IntelliSense works with the paths I set, but the compiler just cannot,  I tried editing the json file several hours last night but still no luck.

Anyone has any idea about this? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Here's part of my c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
{
"version": 4,
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Arduino",
        "compilerPath": "/Users/steveyang/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++",
        "compilerArgs": [
            "-w",
            "-std=gnu++11",
            "-fpermissive",
            "-fno-exceptions",
            "-ffunction-sections",
            "-fdata-sections",
            "-fno-threadsafe-statics",
            "-Wno-error=narrowing"
        ],
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}",
            "/Users/steveyang/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.5/cores/arduino",
            "/Users/steveyang/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.5/variants/standard",
            "/Users/steveyang/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/include",
            "/Users/steveyang/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/include-fixed",
            "/Users/steveyang/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/avr/include"
        ],
        "forcedInclude": [
            "/Users/steveyang/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.5/cores/arduino/Arduino.h"
        ],
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++11",
        "defines": [....
        ],
        "browse": {
            "path":[
                "${workspaceFolder}/",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/include",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include"
            ]    
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: The avr-g++ doesn't have any support for STL (and all c++ style headers without .h). It should be possible to use ArduinoSTL (but it's pre c++11).

Comment: Thanks, so would you recommend to change the compiler?

Comment: Well, more like change of MCU family. For example compilers for ARM based arduinos does support STL libraries (however RTTI and exceptions are usually disabled).